# To open a webpage in a popup dialogue box from a windows application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013

In one of my projects i need to open my webpage(.aspx or .asp) in a popup dialogue box from a windows application.

i tried window.open(), but certainly its not giving me the desired output.

can anyone help me??

Comment: to be specific i want to open my sharepoint application page from microsoft outlook by providing a button/link on outlook toolbar.

Comment: i am using c# language

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving us a lot of information (e.g., C#?, vb.net?, any contextual code relevant to the issue), but as sort of an all-purpose solution to this, you may want to consider using javascript to open the window. You can even run it from server-side by registering the script. I'd provide you with code, but I don't know what language you are using.